# Rename variable names in corrplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have my data as a {instance, feature values} matrix. I want to visualize the correlation of features in Matlab.

Matlab comes with a handy function named [corrplot](http://au.mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html). I get the correlation plot, but with features named as var1, var2, var3 etc., instead of the real feature labels. What is the method of specifying the feature labels to use when plotting the correlations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test the following since I don't have the Econometrics Toolbox, but according to the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html) (and as in many, many, many MATLAB functions) you can provide Name-Value pair arguments to the function in order to set specific parameters.

In your case, you wish to use the `varNames` argument with an appropriate cell array of strings, here `{'instance';'feature';'value'}`, and that should do it.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for referring me to that. I am adding the proper use of function, so that it would help someone like me in future.
    corrplot(featureMatrix,'varNames',featureLabels);